# Compare messages not hides

Tags: magento-1.7, comparison

My problem: when I add to compare product(or remove) messages not hides after I reload the page:

```
The product mytest has been added to comparison list.
The product marine diesel engine M2.02 has been added to comparison list.
The product marine diesel engine M4.17 has been added to comparison list.
The product marine diesel engine M2.02 has been removed from comparison list.
The comparison list was cleared.
```

I searching for that class, but don't find anything. Also I check is my Compare Module is default and it is.

Maybe someone had same problem, or know, what it could be? Thanks.

Comment: Any full page cache or any other cacheing system?